# How to flatten a Pandas dataframe json field that sometimes contains a list and sometimes a value

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe which contains a json field that i need to flatten (and keep the rest of the dataframe fields)  , the confusing part is that this field sometimes(for some records) contains a list, and sometimes only a value(not inside a list)

For example(please run the snippet to see the example of the dataframe):

```html
<table>
<th>rank</th>
<th>Protocol</th>
<th>Type</th>

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>https</td>
<td>{'ResultType': 'regular'}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>https</td>
<td>{'ResultType': ['amp', 'regular']}</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

And the desired result is:

```html
<table>
<th>rank</th>
<th>Protocol</th>
<th>Type</th>

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>https</td>
<td>regular</td>
</tr>



<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>https</td>
<td>amp</td>

<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>https</td>
<td>regular</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

I've been trying the Pandas function json_normalize but honestly the documentation is poor and has few examples so none of muy efforts have ben successfull ,any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the original JSON?  Better to handle this on parse

Comment: Is your input is the first HTML and the desired output is  the second HTML?

Comment: No i used the html to exemplify the dataframe but i thought  it was going to display only the rendered table, not the code, my input is a dataframe similar to the one produced by the first table and the  desired result is a dataframe similar to the second table(please ignore the html i used just to add the tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the following solution:

```
In [10]: columns = ['rank','Protocol','Type']

In [11]: data=np.array([[1,'https',{'ResultType':'regular'}],[2,'https',{'ResultType':['amp','regular']}]])

In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
  rank Protocol                                   Type
0    1    https            {u'ResultType': u'regular'}
1    2    https  {u'ResultType': [u'amp', u'regular']}

In [14]: df['Type'] = df['Type'].apply(pd.Series)

In [15]: df2=df.set_index(['rank', 'Protocol'])['Type'].apply(pd.Series).stack()

In [16]: df2.name='Type'

In [17]: df2.reset_index()[columns]
Out[17]:
   rank Protocol     Type
0     1    https  regular
1     2    https      amp
2     2    https  regular
```

Comment: Worked as expected!